# Getting IllegalStateException while using Jacoco

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, jacoco

I am running a Spring Boot application . While executing the test cases , I am getting below `IllegalStateException`  error

```
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting my/package/chunk/MyItemProcessor with JaCoCo 0.8.8.202204050719/5dcf34a.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_b6258fc.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:161)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_b6258fc.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:111)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_b6258fc.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:92)
        ... 135 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot process instrumented class my/package/chunk/MyItemProcessor. Please supply original non-instrumented classes.
```

My project is a mutlimodule gradle project . Below is my configuration in parent build.gradle file

```
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
    shouldRunAfter spotbugsMain, pmdMain, checkstyleMain
    reports {
        xml.getRequired().set(false)
        csv.getRequired().set(false)
        html.getRequired().set(true)
    }
}

project.ext.jacocoOfflineSourceSets = ['main']
task doJacocoOfflineInstrumentation(dependsOn: [classes, project.configurations.jacocoAnt]) {
    inputs.files classes.outputs.files
    File outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'instrumentedClasses')
    outputs.dir outputDir

    doFirst {
        project.delete(outputDir)
        ant.taskdef(name: 'instrument',
                classname: 'org.jacoco.ant.InstrumentTask',
                classpath: configurations.jacocoAnt.asPath)

        jacocoOfflineSourceSets.each { sourceSetName ->
            def instrumentedClassedDir = "${outputDir}/${sourceSetName}"

            ant.instrument(destdir: instrumentedClassedDir) {
                fileset(dir: "${project.buildDir}/classes/java/${sourceSetName}", includes: '**/*.class')
            }

            //Replace the classes dir in the test classpath with the instrumented one
            sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath -= files(sourceSets[sourceSetName].output.classesDirs)
            sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath += files(instrumentedClassedDir)
        }
    }
}
  test.dependsOn doJacocoOfflineInstrumentation
  check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
```

The below is my configuration for jacoco in my module build.gradle file

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    def minCov =  findProperty('minCov') ?: '0.95'
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#")
    def minimumCoverage = decimalFormat.parse(minCov).doubleValue()
    violationRules {
        failOnViolation = true
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = minimumCoverage
            }
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude:  [
                    "my/package/configuration/*",
                    "my/package/constant/*",
                    "my/package/exception/*",
                    "my/package/lib/dto/*",
                    "my/package/lib/config/*",
                    "my/package/lib/db/*",
                    "my/package/lib/http/*",
                    "my/package/policy/*",
                    "my/package/listener/metric/*"
            ])
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Didi you find a solution to your problem?